# ScrollTop equal a value not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrolltop

I'm trying to run a script when scroll position is a certain value.

Why is this not working?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).scroll(function () {

        if ($(document).scrollTop() == 1500) { 
        $.scrollLock(true);}
    });
</script>
```

When i change == to >= it does work, but that is not what I want. I want it only to work at 1500.

Comment: You only want it to work at *precisely* `1500`? How can you be sure that it will ever reach `1500` precisely?

Comment: try `console.log($(document).scrollTop())`, it is probably skipping 1500, so you might need to change it to something like `>=1500 && < 1520`

Comment: @Ionesomeday, yes. But I getting used to the idea that I have to solve my problem on a different way. Because, what I want is this script to be activated when the user scrolls to one point, but deactivated when the user gives the correct answer to a question. The script i'm activating is a scrolllock script, so I guess scrollTop isn't a solution after all. I wanted to know 1500 exactly, because then I could deactivate it afterwards...

Answer (score 5):

When you scroll in a browser the scrollbar doesn't go down in 1px segments, it jumps around. In Chrome, scrolling by one *segment* takes you up or down by 100px (see [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w7YjX/)).

What you can do is be a bit flexible with your value. Rather then wanting it to fire at exactly 1500px, you can set it to fire between 1450 and 1550. This *should* capture the scroll in most browsers:

```
var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
if (scrollTop >= 1450 && scrollTop <= 1550) { 
    $.scrollLock(true);
}
```

You can then take this a step further by forcing it to 1500 if it falls within that range:

```
if (scrollTop >= 1450 && scrollTop <= 1550) { 
    $(document).scrollTop(1500);
    $.scrollLock(true);
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/w7YjX/1/).

Comment: Sorry, is not working. Check my comment on my question to see what I want to achieve.. Maybe you can help me out when you read my comment.

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, scrolling doesn't go down in 1px segments. A browser could take you from 1499px to 1501px without hitting 1500. What my answer does is capture when you're within that region and force you to 1500 if you're not there exactly.